# Definition of Real Absolute Value

Tags: real-analysis, definition

This definition is correct:

"let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$, $B$ is absolute value of $A$, $B \triangleq|A|$, if $B=\begin{cases} A, & \mbox{if }A \geq0 \\ (-A), & \mbox{if }A \leq 0
\end{cases}$"

??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain the last but one line? Why do you think so?

Comment: You probably mean $-(A)$ where you wrote $(-A)$, even though it is the same thing.

Comment: If you have a working (in the sense that it works as we "intuitively" expect the unitary $-$ to work) definition of $-A$ for $A$ a Dedekind cut, then I see no problem.

Comment: @GitGud, yes, it is same thing... :) thanks!!

Comment: Let's try out your definition with an example: 'let $A,B\in \Bbb R$'. Ok, I choose $A=-3$ and $B=\pi$. Then $\pi:=|-3|=-(-3)=3.$ I don't think so.

Comment: @GitGud, if $A=-3$ and $B=\pi$ then $A\leq 0$ so $B \neq (-A)$, with $(-A)=3$, therefore $B$ is not absolute value of $A$, is correct?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Yes. That's why your definition, the way you wrote it, doesn't work. What you looking for is something like: given $A\in \Bbb R$, define the **absolute value** of $A$ and denote it by $|A|$ as $$|A|=\begin{cases} A, & \mbox{if }A \geq0 \\ (-A), & \mbox{if }A \leq 0
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @GitGud, if you use the symbol $=$ then $|A| \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Yes, $|A|\in \Bbb R$, but that's by definition. You should think of absolute value as a function which is written in sort of an [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation): $$|\cdot |\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R, A\mapsto \begin{cases} A, & \mbox{if }A \geq0 \\ (-A), & \mbox{if }A \leq 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @GitGud, of course.. okok... If I think the absolute value as function then $|A|$ is unique $\forall A \in \mathbb{R}$.. in fact, in my studies I use the symbol $|A|$ to indicate $B \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $B$ is unique! If $B$ is unique then is possible to define absolute value as function!! Is correct  way of thinking?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Yes, that's correct and that's an alternative way to define absolute value. Bu the use of $\iff$ is very important. You didn't use it in your question.

Comment: @GitGud, okok ;) thanks soo much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think it is correct because absolute value just means the distance from the origin.